# Teeth always broken when I rig every character with auto-rig pro

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

Someone here uses Auto-Rig pro ? Sometime I use it,sometime I use Rigify. The problem is that as soon as I rig every humanoid mesh with Auto-Rig pro I have a situation like that you can see below. I don’t know if I rig the character in a wrong way,but the teeth are always broken and I should spend sometime to fix them with the manual weight painting. Instead,this does not happen when I use rigify. I mean,I know how to weight paint a character manually,the problem is that it takes time. I would like that auto rig pro behaves like rigify : the armature should deform correctly the mesh as soon as I bind it to it. Someone of you has a similar problem ? thanks.

[image: a]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatic weights are a feature of Blender, not any individual rig or addon.

The weight calculation uses the bones' **size** and **position** relative to the mesh and each other to calculate which bones receive which weights. Changing this can have an effect on the weight calculation, but can also lead to bad pivot points for bones, so be careful. The algorithm used is also designed to blend weights smoothly between nearby bones, so for things that have fairly rigid assignments such as teeth, having to correct afterwards is very common. It seems like you have got lucky previously with rigify.

In my experience, automatic weights will always require some manual correction for good deformation.

Comment: yes,I agree. Sometime the automatic weights works ok,but not in every situation. For this reason,when it does not work,I use some other tecniques/ addon. I don't think that I'm lucky with rigify,because each time that I rig a character,the teeth are deformed correctly,probably because the armature is placed better than in auto-rig-pro ?

Comment: Hi, Marietto. I just wanted to let you know that I've created an Auto Rig Pro chatroom. I'm hoping that whatever few ARP users there are on this site will eventually begin discussing it there.